# Find where method = true on model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with a method call `due?` on it.

```
def due?
  case self[:occurring]
  when 'yearly'
    last_update = self[:date]
    due         = self[:action]

    today       = Date.today
    this_year   = today.year
    next_year   = this_year + 1

    return (
      last_update >= (Date.new(this_year, due.month, due.day)) &&
      last_update <  Date.new(next_year, due.month, due.day) &&
      !self.open?
    )
  when 'monthly'
    #... TODO
  else
    return self[:date] <= DateTime.now
  end
end
```

It's nothing too bad. The problem is that I need to find all records that are due using the above algorithm/search. I was going to use a scope but I think it's a bit too much for that. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be `LeModel.all.select(&:due?)`, but keep in mind that this will fetch all the records from the database and do the filtering in the Rails process, which can be slow(fetching the records, not doing the filtering). If you have too many records, you'll want to implement `due?` in SQL, so you can do the checks directly the database.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to the one Idan has proposed could be calculating this field in the model's creation time and save it to the database in `due` column.
To do this:

1. Add a migration to add a due field to the DB
2. Add a before_save hook on the model that will `self.due = due?`

After doing that, you can simply query the DB for the due value:`Model.where(due: true)`

Note that if you choose to work this way, you will also have to create a migration to generate a due value in the DB to all model instances that already exist